# Help with search query in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Im still fairly new to codeigniter and am wondering if someone can help me with this please?

Im just trying to do a very basic search query in Codeigniter, but for some reason, the results are ignoring my "status = published" request...

The code is:

```
$this->db->like('title', $term);
$this->db->or_like('tags', $term);
$data['results'] = $this->db->get_where('resources', array('status' => 'published'));
```

And this dosent work either:

```
$this->db->like('title', $term);
$this->db->or_like('tags', $term);
$this->db->where('status', 'published');
$data['results'] = $this->db->get('resources');
```

Im sure its something basic? Help please?

Comment: You could use the query function $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = published'); putting all you SQL query there for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->from('resources');
$this->db->where('status', 'published');
$this->db->like('title', $term);
$this->db->or_like('tags', $term);
$data['results'] = $this->db->get();
```

Also a great resource is the last_query:

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); // Put this after the $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

after executing the query do:

```
var_dump($this->db->last_query());
exit;
```

this will dump in to the screen the query you are doing, I'm almost sure that this will be one sql issue, and this way it will be easy for you to detect the problem.

Regards,
Pedro